# Chrome Packaged Background App Functionality & Behavior

Tags: html, google-chrome, web-applications, background, google-chrome-app

We are exploring the inviting Chrome Packaged Apps for developing our HTML5 based Offline Web-Application and for that, chrome's background apps feature is quite interesting and complies to our requirements. However, i have the following query:
 1. Will the app continue to run in the background if the user has closed the Chrome Browser window? Actually I want to sync my data to an online server and want it to keep running even if the user has closed the browser window.
Can anyone guide is this feature possible in Chrome's packaged background apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following technologies in Chrome Packaged Apps:

- [Alerts API](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/alarms.html): it allows you to schedule periodic runs of a specific piece of code
- [Cloud Service and PushMessaging API](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/cloudMessaging.html): although in experimental state, this API will allow your Chrome App to receive notifications from an third-party, for example your own server. This is, however, not appropriate for broadcasts, as each pushmessage goes to one app and one user per time.